# how to access formbean class obj in jsp page

Tags: jsp, struct, struts

I want to access from bean object in jsp page. How to get that?

1. I have formbean class with customername,date,amount,rate etc with setter() and getter() for the field members.
2. I have data access class where i can get data for the bean class property from database and set data to formbean class object

E.g.:

```
class formbean{
    String amount;
    String rate;

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount=amount
    };

    String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    ...
}

class dao {
    public Formbean fetchcust() {
        loan.setCloseDt11(rs.getString("CloseDt"));
        loan.setAmount11(rs.getString("Amount"));
        loan.setRate11(rs.getString("Rate")); return loan;
    }
}
```

and returning this object.

my question is how to access this object in jsp page

Comment: You should consider reformatting your question to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If your bean is an ActionForm (it’s not clear from your code if it is or not) then Struts exposes this into you JSP files and you have access to it from tags within `<html:form>`. You then just use the `property` attribute on the Struts tags and they will pick that up.

Also, you can have access to it by using JSTL or Struts bean tags since Struts exposes this in the request or session scope as a named attribute (the scope is specified in the `struts-config.xml` file in your `action` definition using the `scope` attribute and the exposed name is the `name` attribute of the same definition).

```
<action
      path="/actionName"
      type="some.package.ActionClass"
      name="yourForm"
      scope="request"
      ...
    >
```

If that form is a standard bean, not extending ActionForm than you must set this in the desired scope by hand using `request.setAttribute(…)` or `session.setAttribute(…)`. Once in the JSP you can retrieve it using again JSTL or Struts bean tags.

Comment: my formbean exteds Action Form..
my dao class returns the "object" of formbean class.in that dao class i set values to the setter() method of formbean class. like
  loan.setAmount(rs.getString(0));
  return obj;
in that case how to access that object in jsp page(the accessing jsp page is "popup window" if i click the button in baseform )